# rank of partitioned matrix with column space information

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let us consider a matrix $X=[A,B,C,D]$. Assume that $[A,B,C]$ has full column rank, but $D$ might be rank deficient. Also, assume that $col(A) \cap col(D) = \emptyset$, $col(B) \cap col(D) = \emptyset$, and $col(C) \cap col(D) = \emptyset$.
In this case, does $rank(X) = rank[A,B,C] + rank(D)$ hold? My cocern is whether there exist some linear combination of $[A,B,C]$ such that $col[A,B,C] \cap col(D)$ is not empty...

Comment: Your notations are not clear, what are $A,B,…$, column vectors ? What does $col(A)$ represents ?

Comment: Sorry, $A,B,C$ and $D$ are all matrices. $col(A)$ denotes the column space of a matrix $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your $A,B,C,D$ are matrices of the same height, you don’t necessarily have
$$ rank \begin{pmatrix} A&B&C&D \end{pmatrix} = rank \begin{pmatrix} A&B&C \end{pmatrix} + rank D$$
You only have
$$ rank \begin{pmatrix} A&B&C&D \end{pmatrix} \leq rank \begin{pmatrix} A&B&C \end{pmatrix} + rank D$$
Since colums of $D$ can be in the generated vector space of colums of $A,B$ and $C$, (the converse is also true) an easy counterexample is given by $A+B=D$

Comment: Many thanks. But I think $A=D$ is excluded by the assumption that $col(A) \cap col(D)$ are empty.

Comment: I gave another counterexample :) It works with you definition, and also column space does not mean anything for me, is it a vector space or juste the set of all columns?

Comment: By $col(A) \cap col(D)$ is empty, I meant that any linear combination $Ax$ is not equal to an linear combination $Dy$ for nonzero $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Ok my example is valid now :)